# How to set the prototype of an anonymous perl function

Tags: perl, mocking

I need to dynamically replace functions with anonymous subs for my mocking framework Test::Mockify. Internely I used Sub::Override.
But I have here an Issue with the prototype of the functions I like to mock. I recognized the Issue because of the warning (Prototype mismatch: sub ($;$) vs none).
In order to show the problem I reproduced the Issue without this frameworks in plain perl.

My example package with a function with prototype:

```
package Hello;
sub FunctionWithPrototype($;$){
    my ($Mandatory, $Optional) = @_;
    return "original. m:$Mandatory. o:$Optional";
}
1;
```

My example test:

```
use Hello;
sub test {
    no warnings 'redefine';
    # no warnings 'prototype'; # This would hide the problem

    is(Hello::FunctionWithPrototype('mand', 'opt'), 'original. m:mand. o:opt' ,'prove return value before change');
    is (prototype('Hello::FunctionWithPrototype'),'$;$', 'Prove prototype output of function');

    my $OriginalCode = *Hello::FunctionWithPrototype{CODE};
    # warn: Prototype mismatch: sub Hello::FunctionWithPrototype ($;$) vs none
    *Hello::FunctionWithPrototype = sub {return 'overriden'};


    is(Hello::FunctionWithPrototype('mand', 'opt'), 'overriden','prove the mocked function');
    # warn: Prototype mismatch: sub Hello::FunctionWithPrototype: none vs ($;$)
    *Hello::FunctionWithPrototype = $OriginalCode; # 

    is(Hello::FunctionWithPrototype('mand', 'opt'), 'original. m:mand. o:opt' ,'prove return value before change (should be as before)');
}
```

I could think of a solution like:

```
my $proto = prototype('FunctionWithPrototype') ? (prototype('FunctionWithPrototype')):undef;
*t::TestDummies::DummyImportTools::Doubler = sub $proto {};
```

But this is , of course, not compiling: 'Illegal declaration of anonymous subroutine', adding a var in the sub is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string [eval](http://p3rl.org/eval):

```
eval "*Hello::FunctionWithPrototype = sub (" .
    prototype('Hello::FunctionWithPrototype') .
    ") {return 'overriden'};";
```

Comment: I thought also about this, but i was not sure if this is a evil hack ;-)
So i did it now like this:
    sub _AddPrototype {my ($Path, $Sub) = @_;
        my $Prototype = prototype($Path);
        if($Prototype){
             my $CodeAsString = B::Deparse->new()->coderef2text($Sub);
            return  eval( "sub ($Prototype) {$CodeAsString};");
        }
        return $Sub;
    }

Answer (score 2):

You want the [Sub::Prototype](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Prototype) module. Use it thus:

```
my $original = \&foo;
my $replacement = sub { ... };
Sub::Prototype::set_prototype(
    $replacement,
    prototype($original)
);
*foo = $replacement;
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided for the eval approach. Works fine for me. Since the eval will swallow possible typos, I throw the Error in order to have useful error messages for debugging.

```
sub AddPrototypeToSub {
    my ($Path, $Sub) = @_;
    my $Prototype = prototype($Path);
    if($Prototype){
         my $SubWithPrototype =  eval( 'return sub ('. $Prototype .') {$Sub->(@_)}');
         die($@) if($@); # Rethrow error if something went wrong in the eval.
        return $SubWithPrototype;
    }
    return $Sub;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clarifying a little bit on [DrHide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/261131/drhyde)'s answer for people who may get confused:

The question is about setting a prototype for an anonymous sub. It's as simple as this:

```
use Sub::Prototype;

BEGIN { # Important
    my $code = sub { ... };
    set_prototype($code, '&@');
}
```

However, as noted in the original answer, if you are replacing the existing definition of a subroutine with a code ref, then that code ref should have the same prototype that was declared for that subroutine. You get the original prototype definition with the function `prototype(\&subroutine_name)`.

Setting it in a `BEGIN` block is important because **prototypes can only be set at compilation time**. It won't matter much if you try to set or change the prototype of a normal subroutine at run time.

[More on Perl execution phases here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2C-UNITCHECK%2C-CHECK%2C-INIT-and-END).

[More on Perl prototypes here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes).